# Python gRPC: How to use the experimental single-threaded implementation?

Tags: python, grpc

I'm building a gRPC service in Python, and trying to improve the latency metrics. I went through the Python gRPC [Performance Best Practices](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/#python) and found the following:

> (Experimental) An experimental single-threaded unary-stream implementation is available via the [SingleThreadedUnaryStream channel option](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/__init__.py#L38), which can save up to 7% latency per message.

The problem is that the link points to a class located in an `experimental` folder, without any usage instructions. I searched the manual (and Github repos in general), but found no reference as to how to enable this feature

**How can I use or call the `SingleThreadedUnaryStream` channel option feature in my code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep dive in the gRPC source code, the following seems to work:

```py
from grpc import experimental

channel_options = [(experimental.ChannelOptions.SingleThreadedUnaryStream, 1)]
with grpc.insecure_channel(f"{HOST}:{PORT}", options=channel_options) as channel:
    stub = xxx_pb2_grpc.XxxStub(channel)
```

However, there was no impact on the latency or thoroughput.